# AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() is not working in android

Tags: android, audio, headset, android-audiomanager

I want to check whether heaset is plugged in or not...
I did it like this

```
 AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
 Log.i("am.isWiredHeadsetOn()", am.isWiredHeadsetOn()+"");
```

But i am always getting false value...

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you testing this on the emulator or an actual device? And what Android OS do you have on the emulator or device?

Comment: I am testing this on Folio 100 Tablet and it has Android 2.2

Comment: This actually should work fine. Can you check your code on other devices then Folio 100?

Comment: Yes i also have checked it on HTC wildfire too and it is giving false.. Is there any permission that i need to add?

Comment: It looks like it should work fine. Are you sure the AudioManager is working properly? Try playing a sound using it like:
    am.playSoundEffect(FX_KEY_CLICK);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug. You will always get `false` when calling `isWiredHeadsetOn` unless your add `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```