# How to Stop musicplayer when I detach headphones?

Tags: android

I want to stop the currently running MusicPlayer when the user unplugs the headphones (both wired & bluetooth).

I came across sevral posts where use of:

```
isWiredHeadsetOn(), isBluetoothA2dpOn()
```

is suggested.

But Android docs says isWiredHeadsetOn() is deprecated. What alternative should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

`isWiredHeadsetOn()` - This method is deprecated. Use only to check is a headset is connected or not.

It sounds like it *is* still recommended for what you're doing, though the docs are worded poorly

Comment: I tried the following code, but it always shows 'Not Connected'

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.handsetcheck);

 TextView tvHeadsetStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeadsetStatus);

 AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 if(audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()) {
    tvHeadsetStatus.setText("Connected");
 }else{
     tvHeadsetStatus.setText("Not Connected");
 }
}`

Comment: Got it thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249884/audiomanager-iswiredheadseton-is-not-working-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

I just read a post where someone was suggesting registering for the ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG broadcast event.

You can apparently get the state of it from: intent.getIntExtra("state", 0));

Answer (score 1):

I use AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY event in my app.
Create your custom broadcast receiver:

```
private class HeadsetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context cntx, Intent intent) 
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.compareTo(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY) == 0)
        {
        }
    }
};  /* end HeadsetIntentReceiver  */
```

Then register receiver:

```
headsetReceiver = new HeadsetIntentReceiver();
mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
mIntentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY);
mParentActivity.registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, mIntentFilter);
```

Don't forget to unregister it later.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for it, it's deprecated but suggested to be used ONLY for checking to see if a headset is connected or not. Should be fine to use.

Comment: True. That's what happens when people update at the same time.