# Doing something if it detects that headphones are plugged in

Tags: android, audio, if-statement, headset

I'm wanting to make it so if headphones are plugged in the device something happens such as a notification icon appears. (I already have the notification icon stuff done) But I can't seem to find a way to make it happen. I'm wanting something like this

```
if headphones_plugged_in {
do this 
}
```

I found this online

```
AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn()
```

I just don't know how I would use that. I already added the right permissions in the manifest too! If you could guide me or link me to something it would be great. Thank You!

Comment: Just put it in an `if` statement? Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: Like how would I make an if statement saying if headphones are plugged in, do this @Femaref

Comment: @FernandoRamirez This is where punctuation becomes important. This totally looks like you just said: "Do this Femaref"

Answer (score 1):

I think your question might have some duplicates:

1. [Check whether headphones are plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395054/check-whether-headphones-are-plugged-in)
2. [Android: Checking if headphones are plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764733/android-checking-if-headphones-are-plugged-in)

The method you want seems to have be deprecated in API level 14.
The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isWiredHeadsetOn%28%29) says to use it **only** to check whether the headset it connected or not. So for your purposes, that will fit. However, to check whether audio is being played though it, you might need a different solution.

From your comment, it looks like you want to know how to actually use it. The function returns true or false to put it in an if statement as the argument and you'll be set.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I only need it to check if they are plugged in though, no need to check if music is playing.

Comment: Then you should be fine with something like what is shown in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249884/audiomanager-iswiredheadseton-is-not-working-in-android)

I haven't done any android dev, but I don't see why (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE).isWiredHeadsetOn() shouldn't work. I'll leave that for someone more experienced

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<receiver>` in your manifest that listens for [the `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG).
The documentation shows `Intent` extras that you can use to find out if the headset is plugged in (`state`), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the `BroadcastReceiver` to get the `android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG` intent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
AudioManager audio=(AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(audio.isWiredHeadsetOn()){
             Toast.makeText(this,"Headset is Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
             Toast.makeText(this,"Headset is Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Thanks guys!